# $state resolve with parameter - AngularJS $StateProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to add a `resolve` to my `$state` in my routing following this guide [here](http://www.dwmkerr.com/promises-in-angularjs-the-definitive-guide/#advancedpromisesrouting).

Going a bit further than the guide by adding parameters to the function things stop working.

my code looks like this

```
'use strict';

angular.module('academiaUnitateApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider, entryService) {
    var getEntry = function(id) {
        entryService.find(id)
            .then(function(response){
                return response.data;
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                return null;
            });
    };

    $stateProvider
        .state('entry', {
            url: '/entry/:id',
            templateUrl: 'app/entry/entry.html',
            controller: 'EntryCtrl',
            resolve: {
                entry: getEntry($state.current.param.id)
            }
        });
  });
```

however my console log looks like this:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module academiaUnitateApp due to: //didn't add this part tell me if needed
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: entryService
```

So from what I can greater is that the entryService provider isn't known, if this is correct how should I add this, instead of the way I'm adding it at the moment.

---

**EDIT**

Here is the entryService

```
'use strict';

angular.module('academiaUnitateApp')
    .factory('entryService',function($http, $state){
        var service = {};

        service.find = function(_id){   
            return $http.get('/api/entrys/' + _id);
        };

        return service;
  });
```

app/app.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('academiaUnitateApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'btford.socket-io',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'textAngular'
])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider
      .otherwise('/');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
  })

  .factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $cookieStore, $location) {
    return {
      // Add authorization token to headers
      request: function (config) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        if ($cookieStore.get('token')) {
          config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookieStore.get('token');
        }
        return config;
      },

      // Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
      responseError: function(response) {
        if(response.status === 401) {
          $location.path('/login');
          // remove any stale tokens
          $cookieStore.remove('token');
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
        else {
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
      }
    };
  })

  .run(function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
    // Redirect to login if route requires auth and you're not logged in
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
      Auth.isLoggedInAsync(function(loggedIn) {
        if (next.authenticate && !loggedIn) {
          $location.path('/login');
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply the dependencies your application module needs. To be able to inject your service, your app must know the module where your `entryService` is defined.

If `academiaUnitateApp.services` is the module name where  `entryService` is defined, you must specify the dependency as below :

```
angular.module('academiaUnitateApp', ['academiaUnitateApp.services'])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, entryService) {
   // ...
});
```

And then you'll be able to inject any service (or controller...) you need in your app.

Comment: updated the question with the `entryService` hope this helps bring some light on the problem.

Comment: Okay, you just have one module. I really advise you to separate your app elements into different module. This project shows good ways to structure your angular projects : https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/app/app.js
Here, if you really want to keep one module, you must define an empty array in your first app module definition. => angular.module('academiaUnitateApp', []).

Comment: I think you are missing a link to the project you are talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I just didn't finished to write my comment. Have a look at my previous comment.

Comment: just had a look at the link you gave, and my `app.js` looks similar to that

Answer (score 1):

Here is my `app.js` (routing rules using state)

```
.state('books.show.detail',{
        url: '/detail/:bookId',
        templateUrl: 'views/book.detail.html',
        controller: 'BookDetailCtrl',
        resolve: {
          bookDetails: function(BookDetailsService,RestClient,$q,$stateParams){
            console.log($stateParams.bookId);
            var book = BookDetailsService(RestClient,$q,$stateParams.bookId);
            return book.get();
          }
        }
      });
```

And here is my `service.js` where `BookDetailsService` is defined

```
var services = angular.module('uiAngularClientApp.services',['ngResource']);

services.factory('RestClient',['$resource', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('http://localhost:8080/books/:id',{id:'@id'});
}]);

services.factory('BookDetailsService',['RestClient','$q',function(RestClient,$q,key){
  return function(RestClient,$q,key){
    return new GetBookDetails(RestClient,$q,key);
  };
}]);

function GetBookDetails($resource, $q, key) {
  this.get = function() {
    var delay = $q.defer();
    $resource.get({id:key},function(book){
      delay.resolve(book)
    },function(){
      delay.reject('Cannot get book details');
    });
    return delay.promise;
  };
};
```

Works perfectly fine. Most important is definition of `BookDetailsService` in `service.js`.